# Wake up android device by microphone or camera

Tags: applications, lock-screens, camera, tablet, microphone

I would like to install a Android tablet on a wall. 
So I would wake it up by looking in to the camera(distance ~0.5 - 2 meters), by clapping my hands or something similar.
Now I'm searching for an app or a service who can handle this.
Something like [ISeeYou](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iseeyoulite), but working...
I will only awake my device, not unlock it.

Comment: Asking how to achieve this is on-topic, but asking for app recommendations is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Voice control apps are plentiful, and a few will work with screen off.  Keeping the camera on all the time would chew up resources too fast so I doubt you'll find a solution there.

This kid has an app that will let Google Now listen with the screen off and then another app that will let you add additional commands.  http://rsenapps.com/